# Bookshelf.js many-to-many | provide table name rather than model as interim

Tags: relationship, bookshelf.js

I'm using [Bookshelf.js](https://bookshelfjs.org/) to develop an application and define models. I have a Post model which has many users who have liked it. I want to define the relationship like this:

```
var Post = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'posts',
    hasTimestamps: true,
    likers: function () {
        return this.hasMany('User').through('likes', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
    },
});
```

the **through()** function accepts only model name as its interim argument which means I have to define a separate model for **likes** table.
Is there any way to user through() function with table name rather than another model?

Comment: Do you need to access or set any other columns on the `likes` table besides `post_id` and `user_id`?

Comment: @devius no when I'm using this relation, I don't need any column  from likes table.

Comment: Then you can probably use `.belongsToMany()` instead of `.hasMany().through()`: https://bookshelfjs.org/api.html#Model-instance-belongsToMany